# Mandatory Roaming Profiles caching

Tags: windows-7-x64, group-policy, roaming-profile

I'm in a Public library scenario and use roaming mandatory profiles locked down with group policies.  If I do not set "Delete cached copies of roaming profiles" in the computer policy, the other policies I have applied do not work correctly (I can access things I should not be able to).  If I do have that setting set to "Enabled", everything works fine.

I would like to be able to cache profiles so they potentially are not downloading at every reboot, but this is a hang up for me.

When I run RSOP or GPresult, it appears that everything is applying, so I am at a loss as to why this doesn't work, but I'm not super familiar with caching profiles, and would appreciate any suggestions.

The clients in question are Windows 7 64 bit, my DC's are windows 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Mandatory profiles are downloaded from the server each time regardless of whether there is a cached copy on the local machine, the cached copy is only there to allow log on if the network is unavalible.

I would just leave the policy enabled.

source: http://www.sepago.de/helge/2010/01/24/are-mandatory-user-profiles-deleted-at-logoff-or-cached/